# run zsh command for all files in a folder

Tags: zsh, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a `models` folder that contains multiple sql files for example `models/mart/table1.sql`, `models/mart/table2.sql`, `models/mart/table3.sql`

I run this command manually on the terminal:

```
dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args '{"model_name": "table1"}'
```

However, instead of running it individually for each table, I want to include it in the Bitbucket pipeline. How can I modify the command such that it runs in a loop? It should be able to extract the tablename (filename) for all files from a specified folder eg `(models/mart)` and then run the command accordingly by replacing the model_name by the filename each time?

```
pipelines:
  custom: 
    dbt-run-default:
          - step:
              name: 'Compile'
              image: fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
              script:
                - cd dbt_4flow
                - dbt deps --profiles-dir ./profiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand which parts of the paths you want to pick apart. Does this work?

```
for file in models/mart/*.sql; do
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    model=${file%/*}
    printf " --args '{\"%s\": \"%s\"}'\n" "$model" "$table"
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}"
done
```

Comment: Can you modify it with the dbt command? I only need the filename from the path. Currently, I added this in the loop: ```dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args '{"model_name": "$table"}'```but I get an error that:  ```Macro 'macro.codegen.generate_model_yaml' (macros/generate_model_yaml.sql) depends on a node named '$table' which was not found```a syntax issue most likely

Comment: That's because there is no parameter substitution of $table within single quotes. I'll have a look.

Comment: I replaced the single quotes with double quotes and escaped the double quotes inside the --args so $table is substituted.

Comment: I looked but am unable to diagnose. I'm neither familiar with dbt nor with yaml. Just a shell guru.